# Fix the background color when the element is transformed

Tags: html, css

Not sure if this is possible to achieve, I have a list of images and I move those images using GSAP library, and each list item has a background color, which needs to be retained or preserved when the item is moved, mean to say, the background color must stay and only the list item must be moved

Codepen: https://codepen.io/nagshankar/pen/ExwOgOa

```
<div>   
 <ul id="freds">

   <li class="ibu">
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/32887/fred.svg"/>
   </li>
  <li class="us">
     <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/32887/fred-pink.svg"/>
 </li>

 </ul>

  <button onclick="ibu()">IBU</button>
  <button onclick="us()">US</button>

</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#freds{position:absolute;bottom:50px}
#freds li{display:inline-block;list-style:none;background:#999999;}
```

Comment: When you say ‘only the list item must move’ do you mean only the figure must move but the gray square must remain? I don’t understand why you are moving the whole li in that case. Have I misunderstood what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to move the `image` you simply need to target the image and not the `li`:

```js
function ibu(){
   gsap.to('#freds li img', {y:0})
  gsap.to('#freds li.ibu img', {y:-300})
}
function us(){
  gsap.to('#freds li img', {y:0})
  gsap.to('#freds li.us img', {y:-300})
}
```

working example:

```js
function ibu() {
  gsap.to('#freds li img', {
    y: 0
  })
  gsap.to('#freds li.ibu img', {
    y: -300
  })
}

function us() {
  gsap.to('#freds li img', {
    y: 0
  })
  gsap.to('#freds li.us img', {
    y: -300
  })
}
```

```css
#freds {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 100px
}

#freds li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  background: #999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<ul id="freds">

  <li class="ibu">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/32887/fred.svg" />
  </li>
  <li class="us">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/32887/fred-pink.svg" />
  </li>

</ul>

<button onclick="ibu()">IBU</button>
<button onclick="us()">US</button>
```

Comment: you can add this ias an example: https://codepen.io/kareemda/pen/jOYEWQO